# How do I prevent socket.io from emitting events sequentially/automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I just started using socket.io on my node.js-server. I just want to emit an event whenever I do a post request to the server via clicking on a button. The problem is that the event is already being emitted when I load the page and then will be emitted every two minutes again. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this? I just want the event to be fired once after I clicked on the button.

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

app.post('/event', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('emit event')
  io.emit('event')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

server.listen(8085)
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="fire">Fire!</button>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
$('#fire').on('click', function () {
  console.log('fire!')
  $.ajax({
    url: '/event',
    method: 'POST'
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log('done')
    alert(data)
  }).fail(function (data) {
    console.log('fail')
    alert(data)
  })
})

$(function () {
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8085')
  var container = $('.container')

  socket.on('event', function (bcevent) {
    console.log('got event')
    var newItem = '<p>EVENT</p>'
    container.append(newItem)
  })

  var jqxhr = $.post('/event', function () {
        // alert( "success" );
  })
        .done(function () {
            // alert( "second success" );
        })
        .fail(function () {
            // alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function () {
            // alert( "finished" );
        })
})
```

Thank you very much for your time and efforts.

Comment: It looks like you are executing a POST request to server. Remove the 'var jqxhr = ... ' line and it should work as expected.

Comment: The event is not emitted on page load anymore. But whenever I click the button and wait for two minutes, the server emits the event again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the result of two things:

1. You make a request when the page is loaded:

   var jqxhr = $.post('/event', function () {
2. Some browsers (including Chrome) might retry the request every two minutes if it fails or doesn't return. Make sure there's no breakpoint in the server and that the server sends a response with code 200.

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint does not return anything to client. Some browsers are retrying the request in this case.

Make sure to return some result to client after event is emitted, e.g.:

```
app.post('/event', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('emit event');
  io.emit('event');
  res.status(200).send();
});
```